# Almost any type from "any" (any, but one)

Tags: typescript

Is it possible in Typescript to assign a type to a variable, whose values could be any value from "any", but one (or any other amount). For example:

```
let variable: NOT<any, 'number'>
```

This variable can be of absolutely any type, apart from 'number'.

Answer (score 4):

In Typescript there is the `Exclude` helper, which leverages Conditional Types introduced in v2.8. `Exclude<T, U>` is just `T extends U ? never : T`, i.e. if `val` in the example below happens be to be `number` it will fail, due to the `never` type, otherwise the type is any type `T`:

```
function test<T>(val: Exclude<T, number>): void {
    console.log('not a number!');
}

test('a');
test([1]);
test(1); // fails
```

Comment: But how can I assign this type to a variable? I tried using Exclude this way: `Exclude<any, number>`, but it was just giving `any` as a type.